# Xpath: How to find the parent of all descendants of the node matching the specified xpath condition?

Tags: xpath

There are HTML:

```
<article>
//some levels...
  <div class="address item">
    <a class="address">
      Address 1
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="address item">
    <a class="address">
      Address 2
    </a>
  </div>
</article>
<article>
//some levels...
  <div class="address item">
    <a class="address">
      Address 2
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="address item">
    <a class="address">
      Address 3
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="address item">
    <a class="address">
      Address 4
    </a>
  </div>
</article>  
<article>
//some levels...
  <div class="address item">
    <a class="address">
      Address 1
    </a>
  </div> 
</atricle>
```

I need find `article` where NO text `Address 1` in all `a` elements (only one `article` in this example). I use `(//div[@class="address item"]/descendant::a[not(contains(text(), "Address 1"))])/ancestor::article` but it still find `article` where are `Address 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one and let me know if it still doesn't meet requirements:

```
//article[not(.//a[normalize-space(text())="Address 1"])]
```

Comment: @Anderson, can you tell me will this work or not? `//article[not(//a[contains(text(), 'Address 1')])]` I am not sure with this so i am asking to you.

Comment: No. You should specify *context* - `.//a` instead of `//a`. `//article[not(//a[contains(text(), 'Address 1')])]` means return `article` if there is no `a` that contains `Address 1` **in the whole document** while `//article[not(.//a[contains(text(), 'Address 1')])]` means return `article` if there is no descendant `a` **in this `article`** that contains `Address 1`

Comment: Also note that `text()="Address 1"` will match **exact** text content while `contains(text(), 'Address 1')` - **only part** of text content, so `"Address 1 or something"`, `"something and Address 1"` also will be matched

Comment: Thanks Mate, For sharing your knowledge. :)

Comment: Andersson I use `contains()` because actually text 'Address 1' is '      Address 1         ' .That is, in the text there are spaces. So your expression finds all generally `article`'s.

Comment: @Valentina, If there are spaces around text, try `//article[not(.//a/normalize-space(text())="Address 1")]`

Comment: jainish kapadia `//article[not(//a[contains(text(), 'Address 1')])]` somehow doesn't find anything

Comment: Andersson it is weird but //article[not(.//a/normalize-space(text())="Address 1")] doesn't find anything

Comment: Are you sure that provided piece of `HTML` has same structure as your real `HTML`?

Comment: I understand why your and jainish kapadia's expression not find anything/ Because text 'Address 1' is '" Address 1 "' therefore, strict compliance or normalizing whitespace finds nothing. But I need use text Address 1 without extra quotation marks... Because there need use contains() function...

Comment: Ok. Then use `//article[not(.//a/normalize-space(text())='"Address 1"')]`

Comment: `//a[normalize-space(text())="Address 1"]` find the needed `a` elements. But   `//article[not(.//a/normalize-space(text())='"Address 1"')]` does not work

Comment: Are you sure that provided piece of HTML has same structure as your real HTML -- yes I'm sure

Comment: And so I need find `article`, but all yours expressions find `a` element.

Comment: It's definitely can't be true:) My expression could find `article` only! Don't you miss something? Are you sure you correctly use it?

Comment: Thanks, Andersson, it works, albeit in a slightly modified form: `//article[not(.//a[normalize-space(text())="Address 1"])]` A little change your answer please and I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: I'm glad too) Checked)

Comment: `No. You should specify context - .//a instead of //a. //article[not(//a[contains(text(), 'Address 1')])] means return article if there is no a that contains Address 1 in the whole document while //article[not(.//a[contains(text(), 'Address 1')])] means return article if there is no descendant a in this article that contains Address`  when you write //a it would automatically search for a whole document, so it searches the whole document where there is no <a>

Comment: `if there is no descendant a in this article that contains Address 1` what do you mean by in this article? You are actually searching article. Eh?

Comment: Article without specific descendant